# How do I knit my r script file into html file on rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

so I was having a problem with my rmd file so I had to switch my work from rmd to a brand new r script and now it's not showing me the option to knit to html anymore.

I've also included photos of what the picture of what the top of my r file now looks like and what the top of my rmd file looks like

https://imgur.com/a/8JRmkKP

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example:  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example> with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Can you make a new file that’s an rmd and paste your script into it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file is saved and in the current working directory and try running

```r
knitr::spin("your-r-script-file.R")
```

in R console, you should then have a new HTML file next to your R script.
[image: knitr::spin]